# How can I asynchronously retrieve data and modify it with a Tokio-based echo server?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I am working on an echo server which takes data from TCP and applies some logic to that data. For example, if the client data comes in as `hello` I want to respond it as`hello from server`.

I am able to forward the input data using the `copy` function, but this is not useful in my case.

Here is the starting code that I am working on:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::Future;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio_core::net::TcpListener;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use tokio_io::io::copy;
use tokio_io::AsyncRead;

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:15000".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr, &handle).unwrap();
    println!("Listening on: {}", addr);

    let done = socket.incoming().for_each(move |(socket, addr)| {
        let (reader, writer) = socket.split();
        let amt = copy(reader, writer);

        let msg = amt.then(move |result| {
            match result {
                Ok((amt, _, _)) => println!("wrote {} bytes to {}", amt, addr),
                Err(e) => println!("error on {}: {}", addr, e),
            }

            Ok(())
        });

        handle.spawn(msg);

        Ok(())
    });

    core.run(done).unwrap();
}
```

I know that I need to add some logic instead of this copy function but how?

```
let amt = copy(reader, writer);
```

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with Tokio (hence why I'm not writing a full answer), but I think you'd need to `read_to_end` from the socket into a buffer, append the extra data into the buffer, and then `write_all` from the buffer to the socket. The Tokio docs have [an example](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/io/#using-the-future-api) of using the `read`/`write` helpers that you could probably adapt to your use case.

Comment: It is rather unclear to me what exactly your problem is, and what you tried.  The code you showed is just a copy of the echo server example from Tokio, without any modifications, so it doesn't look like you tried anything at all so far.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I put the code to explain the context that I am working on. The opening socket and running them via tokio core will be the same. I am currently trying to get the data as framed from socket but I am not sure how to send it back to client after I changed it.

Comment: It sounds like you want an answer to *write your code for you*. That doesn't feel in the spirit of Stack Overflow to me.

Comment: @AkinerAlkan Just to expand this a bit more, questions on Stack Overflow shoud be about one specific problem, so the answer can benefit many people.  For this reason, we need to understand what exactly you have trouble with.  A question simply saying "I copied this example and want to change it in this way, but I don't really know how" doesn't really fit with this approach, so you would be better off asking on Reddit or the Rust user forums.  These sites have a broader scope than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An echo server is kind of special in a sense, that exactly one "request" from a client is followed by exactly one response from the server. A very nice example for such a use-case is tokio's [TinyDB example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/2f690d30bc061a8595744e34fde371882b676a86/examples/tinydb.rs).

One thing that should be considered, however, is that while UDP is based on packets, that hit the other side in the exact form that you sent them with, TCP is not. TCP is a stream protocol - it has strong guarantees relating that a packet was received by the other side and that the data sent is received in exactly the order it was sent in. However, what is not guaranteed is, that one call to "send" on the one side leads to exactly one "receive" call on the other side, returning the exact same chunk of data that was sent. This is especially of interest when sending very long chunks of data, where one send maps to multiple receives. Thus you should settle for a delimiter that the server can wait for before trying to send a response to the client. In Telnet, that delimiter would be "\r\n".
That is where tokio's Decoder/Encoder infrastructure comes to play. An example implementation of such a codec is [LinesCodec](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.11/tokio/codec/struct.LinesCodec.html). If you want to have
Telnet, this does exactly what you want. It will give you exactly one message at a time and allow you to send exactly one such message at a time as response:

```
extern crate tokio;

use tokio::codec::Decoder;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::codec::LinesCodec;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:15000".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();

    let socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();
    println!("Listening on: {}", addr);

    let done = socket.incoming()
        .map_err(|e| println!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
        .for_each(move |socket| {
            // Fit the line-based codec on top of the socket. This will take on the task of
            // parsing incomming messages, as well as formatting outgoing ones (appending \r\n).
            let (lines_tx, lines_rx) = LinesCodec::new().framed(socket).split();

            // This takes every incomming message and allows to create one outgoing message for it,
            // essentially generating a stream of responses.
            let responses = lines_rx.map(|incomming_message| {
                // Implement whatever transform rules here
                if incomming_message == "hello" {
                    return String::from("hello from server");
                }
                return incomming_message;
            });

            // At this point `responses` is a stream of `Response` types which we
            // now want to write back out to the client. To do that we use
            // `Stream::fold` to perform a loop here, serializing each response and
            // then writing it out to the client.
            let writes = responses.fold(lines_tx, |writer, response| {
                //Return the future that handles to send the response to the socket
                writer.send(response)
            });

            // Run this request/response loop until the client closes the connection
            // Then return Ok(()), ignoring all eventual errors.
            tokio::spawn(
                writes.then(move |_| Ok(()))
            );

            return Ok(());
        });

    tokio::run(done);
}
```